# java: add object to new ArrayList without need to parameterize the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, parameterized

I need to add object to new ArrayList:

```
private Map<String,List<MyObject>> populateMapFromList2(List<MyObject> dataSourceList){
Map<String,List<MyObject>> moMap = new HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();
for (MyObject mo : dataSourceList){
    String firstLetter = (mo.getName().substring(0,1)).toUpperCase();
    if (!moMap.containsKey(firstLetter)) {
        moMap.put(firstLetter,new ArrayList<MyObject>());
    }
    moMap.get(firstLetter).add(mo);
}
return moMap;
```

`}`

in the line:`new ArrayList<MyObject>()` I want to add `mo`
Like: `new ArrayList<DataSource>().add(mo)`

but it is a boolean value (Go figure).
is there another way to add value for the first time to not parametrized list?
or the only way is this?
`List<MyObject> initList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
initList.add(mo);
moMap.put(firstLetter,initList);`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the following syntax:

```
List<MyObject> initList = new ArrayList<MyObject>() {{ add(mo); }}
```

Or using **Google Guava**, you can use `Lists.newArrayList(mo)`.

You should consider using a [MultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for what you are trying to achieve (a Map whose values are Lists). Note that Apache Common has a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) implementation too, you can also take a look at the [DefaultedMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/DefaultedMap.html) class.

Comment: I think this is an inner class? I still have to parametrize "initList" and it is still another line.

Comment: No this is an instance initialization. You should consider using a `MultiMap`, or create your own implementation of a `DefaultedMap` that will return you an empty List when calling `get()` on a non existing key. Now if you really want a one liner, make all your variables final, and use it: `moMap.put(firstLetter, moMap.containsKey(firstLetter) ? new ArrayList<Object>() {{ addAll(moMap.get(firstLetter)); add(mo); }} : new  ArrayList<Object>() {{ add(mo); }});`

Answer (score -1):

If using google-guava is an option, you can do `Lists.newArrayList(mo)`.

The documentation is available on the [google-guava API page for Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29).

**EDIT** Non google-guava option:

If google-guava is not an option, you can implement it yourself like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> newArrayList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(a));
}
```

This uses a combination of varargs and generics to create the array list. Varargs allows you to specify a variable number of parameters to this function. The generic type  allows the type of the parameters to be captured and a list of corresponding type to be returned.

Comment: Thanks, But no it is not an option.

Comment: I have added a non-guava option in the answer.